# Align include images to base when using to Html.fromText

Tags: android

I have a code like this.

```
Button b = findViewById(R.id.button);
mImgGetter = new MiniImageGetter(this);
b.setText(Html.fromText("<img src=\"foo\"> FOO!"),mImgGetter,null)
```

where MiniImageGetter is a class like:

```
class MiniImageGetter implements ImageGetter {
    private Context mContext;

    public MiniImageGetter(Context c) {
        mContext =c;
    }

    @Override
    public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
         Drawable d = mContext.getResources().getDrawableR.drawable.foo);
         d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
         return d;

    }
}
```

But the images are all aligned to the bottom of the Button text and not to baseline of the text.

Answer (score 1):

I did not found a real solution but as workaround this works:

```
private SpannableString getSpannableString(int image, int buttontext) {
    Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(image); 

    SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("  " + getString(buttontext));
    d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight()); 
    ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(d, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE); 
    ss.setSpan(span, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
    return ss;
}
```

and then use

```
 b.setText(getSpannableString(R.drawable.foo,"Text with image in front of it"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for aligning inline images with text.

```
public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
    BitmapDrawable d = ...;
    d.setBounds(new Rect(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight() + 5));
    d.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
    return d;
}
```

Comment: Where does the +5 come from? Is that some value that just "works"?

Comment: It works in my case. Depends on a font size so you can adjust this value to match your requirements. I used constant value, but you can calculate it.

Comment: I think setBounds works with Pixels and depending on the dpi and font sizes the value 5 should be different.